# D3JS: Unable to make a bar chart to be responsive on resize

Tags: d3.js

I'm implementing a code in which the width of the container of the svg adapts to the screen on resize. Strangely, despite I'm using the same scale for the x axis to build the bars based on the data (years) they don't move along width the x Axis, instead it goes out of the viewport on resize. Any suggestion to figure out what I am doing wrong would be highly appreciated. I'll leave a running snippet so that you can see the code and the current behavior. I would also like to know how to move the year ticks so that they don't start in the very Y axis but some space to the right so that for better visualization. Thanks

```js
var data = [
 {year: 2000, population: 1192},
 {year: 2001, population: 1234},
 {year: 2002, population: 1463},
 {year: 2003, population: 1537},
 {year: 2004, population: 1334},
 {year: 2005, population: 1134},
 {year: 2006, population: 1234},
 {year: 2007, population: 1484},
 {year: 2008, population: 1562},
 {year: 2009, population: 1427},
 {year: 2010, population: 1325},
 {year: 2011, population: 1484},
 {year: 2012, population: 1661},
 {year: 2013, population: 1537},
 {year: 2014, population: 1334},
 {year: 2015, population: 1134},
 {year: 2016, population: 1200}
];


var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y");


function type(dataArray) {
 dataArray.forEach(function(d) {
  d.year = parseDate(d.year);
  d.retention = +d.population;
 });
 return dataArray;
}
data = type(data);



var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},

    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var xScale = d3.scaleTime();
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);


var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yScale);





var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var artboard = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }));
yScale.domain([
  d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.population - 200 }), 
  d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.population + 200 })
 ]);




var xAxisEl = artboard.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");


var yAxisEl = artboard.append("g")
  .call(yAxis);


function drawChart() {

 width = parseInt(d3.select('body').style('width'), 10) - margin.left - margin.right;
 

 svg.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right);

 xScale.range([0, width]);
 

 xAxis.scale(xScale);
 

 xAxisEl.call(xAxis);
 
 var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .attr("class","rects2")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("fill","#BC204D")
 
 
  rects.attr("y", function(d) {
   return height - yScale(d.population)
  })
   .attr("height", 0)
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.population);
    })
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("transform", function (d, i) {

    return "translate(" + (xScale(d.year) + margin.left)   + "," + margin.bottom + ")"
  })
  .attr("fill","#00338D")

}

drawChart();
  
window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the merge function when updating. Check this out for more info [Update Pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/d3indepth/e25e81566cea413de9873b9339fa7518)

You can use `axis.tickPadding("10")` for padding tick values

```js
var data = [
 {year: 2000, population: 1192},
 {year: 2001, population: 1234},
 {year: 2002, population: 1463},
 {year: 2003, population: 1537},
 {year: 2004, population: 1334},
 {year: 2005, population: 1134},
 {year: 2006, population: 1234},
 {year: 2007, population: 1484},
 {year: 2008, population: 1562},
 {year: 2009, population: 1427},
 {year: 2010, population: 1325},
 {year: 2011, population: 1484},
 {year: 2012, population: 1661},
 {year: 2013, population: 1537},
 {year: 2014, population: 1334},
 {year: 2015, population: 1134},
 {year: 2016, population: 1200}
];


var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y");


function type(dataArray) {
 dataArray.forEach(function(d) {
  d.year = parseDate(d.year);
  d.retention = +d.population;
 });
 return dataArray;
}
data = type(data);



var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},

    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var xScale = d3.scaleTime();
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);


var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yScale).tickPadding("10");





var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var artboard = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }));
yScale.domain([
  d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.population - 200 }), 
  d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.population + 200 })
 ]);




var xAxisEl = artboard.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");


var yAxisEl = artboard.append("g")
  .call(yAxis);


function drawChart() {

 width = parseInt(d3.select('body').style('width'), 10) - margin.left - margin.right;
 

 svg.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right);

 xScale.range([0, width]);
 

 xAxis.scale(xScale);
 

 xAxisEl.call(xAxis);
 
 var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .attr("class","rects2")
  .data(data);
  
  rects.enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("fill","#BC204D").attr("y", function(d) {
   return height - yScale(d.population)
   }).merge(rects)
   .attr("height", 0)
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.population);
    })
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
    return "translate(" + (xScale(d.year) + margin.left)   + "," + margin.bottom + ")"
  })
  .attr("fill","#00338D");
     rects.exit().remove();
}

drawChart();
  
window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
```